# .htaccess to change the domain in the URL

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following two WordPress sites.

1. test.mysite.com
2. mysite.com

The uploads(images) folder is on mysite.com and I want all image URLs from test.mysite.com to be redirected to mysite.com

For example the link `test.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/image.jpg` should be redirected to `mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/09/image.jpg`

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you care about your website traffic and SEO. I would recommend using 301 redirection which is: **RedirectMatch permanent**

It's quite easy! Make an new .htaccess file at test.mysite.com > Just add this chunk of codes bellow:

> RewriteEngine On
>
> RedirectMatch permanent ^/wp-content/uploads/(.*)$ http://mysites.com/wp-content/uploads/$1

Now all images Should be 301 SEO redirected to the concerned location.

Answer (score 1):

You can place this redirect rule **just below `RewriteBase` line**:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^test\.(mysite\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/.+)$ http://%1/$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```